# Unable to setup FTP access to Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2008 R2 instance

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, ftp

I'm trying to set up FTP access to my Windows 2008 R2 instance. I have followed the guide here:

http://handziuk.com/blog/post/2014/10/01/setting-up-ftp-access-to-windows-2008-r2-through-amazon-ec2

and here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470039/how-to-enable-ftp-passive-mode-for-amazon-ec2-server-with-iis

I have done the following:

1. Installed FTP services in IIS
2. Set up an FTP site in IIS pointing to the directory where I want the files to be accessed.
3. Configured FTP firewall support at the server level using ports 41000-41099 and external IP address of my elastic IP
4. Run the following:

   ```
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=FTP_Service action=allow service=ftpsvc protocol=TCP dir=in

   netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
   ```
5. Added the necessary inbound rules in the instances security group for ports 41000-41099 and 21
6. Restarted the FTP service.

However In FileZilla I am still unable to connect using the elastic IP and my Administrator login credentials. I get this error:

```
Status: Connecting to Elastic IP...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Connection closed by server
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to Elastic IP...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Connection closed by server
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: In this case, the best troubleshooting optiong is to disable WIndows Firewall altogether.
First, allow everything and see what happens.
Then, and only *then*, taylor it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open port 21 by Security Group settings? ([AWS Security Group settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/getting-started-create-security-group.html))